Having an issue with Tyranobuilder, unexpected character issue
I am building a game using Tyranobuilder, I defined a character focus behavior on game settings, such that when a character joins the scene and speaks, they will be bright and when another character joins the scene and speaks the former one will fade and the new one will be bright.
This works fine all throughout the game.
I defined two new characters called Clone1 and Clone2 with their respective pictures clone1.png and clone2.png in separate folders. Problem I am facing is that, they do not follow the same rule & behavior as the other characters. Clone 1 joins the scene, and immediately fades out even before Clone2 joins to speak. They have a conversation and none of them follow the mentioned rules. What do you think can be the issue?
Thank you

Seems like this issue with the focus highlighting can be resolved by forcing the clearance by using tag
Another way is to ensure the character joining the scene should have the same name.
Also you can watch this video for learning how to use TyranoBuilder's scripts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFu6p1JtDrE
